# Best way to make Camera App in Android Studio without intents & without deprecated code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-camera2

Title says it all. A lot of tutorials are focusing on this intents thing, which (despite it being easy to code) in my opinion is ridiculous. How does opening the native camera app provide a good user experience?

Anyhow, I've found some tutorials showing the same thing using SurfaceView, but I just cant get that to work at all. It uses a lot of deprecated code, which from what I understand should still work, but, it doesn't for me. I don't get any errors either, it just doesn't show anything.

Do any of you know some tutorials, or can tell me the most modern and up to date way of making an app that 
1) shows you the camera view in the app
2) lets you press a button to take a photo and 
3) lets you store that photo for later use

I appreciate any help in not looking like an ass in front of my group tomorrow. I've been racking my brain over this for the last week, and just when something starts to make sense, it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

The Android documents have a pretty good one [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html). It basically covers everything you are looking for in terms of how to use the camera without starting the native camera activity.

Comment: I tried that and got the following error for the surfaceChanged() method in the CameraPreview class:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.aaa.anidextest, PID: 3730
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
                      at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
                      at com.example.aaa.anidextest.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:65)



I think it might have to do with the size of the camera, but the guide isn't terribly clear on how to fix that.

Comment: @DanRICN that would be a different question. Honestly, it sounds like I answered your first question. I'd suggest you mark this one as accepted, and then post a new one with your bug. Mostly because by making it a new question you'll get more views on it (since it's newer) and you can format the question better by listing the bug and the code you are using which causes the bug. Just a suggestion :)